# Angularjs how to get filename extension?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Hi I am developing angularjs application. I am doing file upload module. I am trying to validate the files. I want to upload only xlsx or xls files. I have developed directive and factory method to upload files as below.

```
myapp.directive('fileModel', ['fileUploadExcel', function (fileUploadExcel) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("change", function (evt) {
                fileUploadExcel.pendingFiles[attrs.fileModel] = evt.target.files[0];
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Below is my controller.

```
 $scope.upload = function (filename) {
 fileUploadExcel.doUpload().success(function (success) {
 }).error(function (error) {
});
```

Below is my factory code.

```
myapp.factory('fileUploadExcel', ['$http', '$cookieStore', 'cfg', function ($http, $cookieStore, cfg) {
    var LoginID = $cookieStore.get("LoginID");
    var baseurl = cfg.Baseurl;
    var fileuploadurl = baseurl + 'api/Customer/BulkUploadVehicle/';

    var service = {
        uploadUrl: fileuploadurl,
        pendingFiles: {},
        doUpload: doUpload
    };
    return service;
    function doUpload() {
        var filename;
        var files = new FormData();
        files.append('LoginID', LoginID);
        angular.forEach(this.pendingFiles, function (value, index) {
            filename = value.name;
            files.append(index, value);
        });
        var extn = filename.split(".").pop();
        if (extn == 'xlsx' || extn == 'xls') {
            return $http.post(this.uploadUrl, files, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined
                }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        } 
    }
}]);
```

I am able to get extn successfully. When my files are of type excel my code works fine. Whenever i upload other than excel i am getting error. I have wrote return false. This is not working here. I should return something else may be. May i know what i should write in else case? Can anyone help me out here? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what exactly happens when you try to upload files other than xlsx or xls extensions? does it pass the if condition?

Comment: Thank you rahul. Whenever i upload other than excel i am getting error fileUploadExcel.doUpload(...).success is not a function

Comment: ahh..got it.. Check the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return different type:

on success,  you return a $http promise in your factory, so you can call success & error function in your controller whith that:

`fileUploadExcel.doUpload().success()` **exist!**

but if error, you return false in your factory, in this case this is a boolean and is not a $http promise so you cant use success & error function.

`fileUploadExcel.doUpload().success()` **doesnt exist and return an error**

Of course a solution is to check if the returning value is not false and continue your code, but I suggest to return always a promise by resolving it if success and  rejecting it on error, **so the promise chain is a not broken.**

PS: $http is a modified promise why they have success & error, but I suggest using the vanilla promise and using .then()

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

if (extn === 'xlsx' || extn === 'xls') {
    $http.post(this.uploadUrl, files, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
         headers: {
             'Content-Type': undefined
         }
    }).success(function(success) {
        deferred.resolve(success);
    }).error(function(error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
} else {
    deferred.reject('File format not supported');
}
return deferred.promise;
```

and your controller:

```
$scope.upload = function (filename) {
    fileUploadExcel.doUpload().then(function (success) {
        //success
    }, function (error) {
        //error
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should i declare $q  anywhere? I am getting $q is not defined

Comment: $q should be injected in your factory https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I had no idea about q. I gone through asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 3):

The error is thrown when `doUpload()` returns `false`. Since `false` is a boolean and not a promise, there is `.success()` won't be defined.

Instead of returning `false` I suggest you return a rejected promise when the file is not an excel file along the lines of: 
`return $q.reject("File type not supported: " + extn);`

Comment: Too be clear, to do this you need to inject the `$q` service into the `fileUploadExcel` factory similarly to how you've injected `$http`.

Answer (score 1):

Tried doing this instead?

```
$scope.upload = function (filename) {
  var promise = fileUploadExcel.doUpload(); //gets promise object in a variable
  if(promise){ // if variable is not false or null, handle resolution
     promise.success(function (success) { }).error(function (error) {});
  }
}
```

Or you can return `null` in `else` in your factory and do a null check. The code above will remain same.